# Gateway Server in rdesktop

Tags: remote-desktop, remmina, rdesktop, terminal-server

I know that Microsoft servers follow RDP 6.x and that somehow Remmina doesn't seem to support this.

Is there a Remote Desktop Client around that will support TS connections?

Answer (score 0):

freerdp, which underlies remmina's rdp access does kinda support it. It is the only client I've found that does and have been able to get work, but it is very buggy and hard to get installed the version that does support it when I tried on 13.10. I haven't tried on 14.04 yet.

There is a feature request here if you'd like to support the enhancement.
https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/issues/347

Comment: what options did you use? I'm looking at the man pages for `xfreerdp` and not seeing anything related to "Gateway" or "TS" gateway, or anything useful at all.

Comment: You want to look for the /g options: /g:GATEWAY 
/gd:GATEWAYDOMAIN /gu:GATEWAYUSERNAME /gp:GATEWAYPASSWORD